# hook_theme_suggestions_hook_alter() not working for Views

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to create a custom template for a view page in Drupal 8.3.x. It's going in a custom theme, and needs to be a view-level template (so not page- or node-).

I've been fighting with it for a while and figured it might be an issue with the specific name, so I've made the code as sparse as possible - still no luck.

I have the following code in mytheme.theme:

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_views_view_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $suggestions[] = 'test_template';
}
```

And the following file structure:

```
- mytheme
  ~ templates
    * test-template.html.twig
  ~ mytheme.theme
  ~ mytheme.info.yml
  ~ ... etc.
```

I know that the theme_suggestions alter function is working properly; I have Twig debugging enabled, and when I pull up my site and look at the code, I can see the following: (note the "X" next to views-view.html.twig showing that as the currently used Twig file)

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * test-template.html.twig
   x views-view.html.twig
-->
```

So it's adding the suggestion. And the template file is named correctly. I know it's not a directory issue, because I have other .html.twig files in that /templates/ folder that are working correctly.

Does anyone know why the file name suggestion is working, but the matching file isn't?

---

Edit: Kevin pointed out a possible duplicate ticket in the comment below. That's only half-related. It does solve the **symptom** in this particular example - I have been able to pull in one of the templates mentioned here, and it works for this case.

However, the title of the ticket and general issue still holds. I can't get the hook_theme_suggestions_hook_alter() to work with my custom theme_suggestion / template. While it turns out the view I used as my example could be solved another way, there are other instances where that won't be the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a template for a specific view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188529/create-a-template-for-a-specific-view)

Comment: I _think_ the linked question here can help. You don't necessarily need to invent new naming suggestions, there should be a handful to pick from. They're just not easy to come across.

Comment: @Kevin - In this case, I do need a new naming suggestion. I've been through the default suggestions, and there is no view-level default naming suggestion that pulls in the specific view ID.

If you know of one I haven't found, I'd be happy to use it, but everything I've searched has turned up no default options. Thus, the hook_alter function above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution. As it turns out, for some reason Drupal doesn't play nicely with custom theme suggestions starting with a word + single dash.

I updated my HOOK_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() function to include `$suggestions[] = 'test__template';` (with 2 underscores between the words) and updated my template name to `test--template.html.twig` (with 2 dashes to match the 2 underscores), and everything works as expected.

Comment: Perfect. Good question. Good answer. For others, just to be crystal clear, you need to replace ***all*** hyphens in the suggestion to underscores.