# Twig template for just one page in a view

Tags: views, theming

I have a Drupal view (*Product Section*) where I have a master view. This is the view I'm currently using for *Computers*, *Cell Phone*, and other pages I am still creating.

> [image: screenshot]

I also have a *Product Shop* page, which is almost like the parent page. For this page, the path is */products*, for *Computers* is */products/computers*, and so forth.

In my theme folder, inside of the *templates* folder, I created a *page--products.html* template. This works great, but this template gets used not only by the */products* pages but also the *products/page-name-here* pages.

1. How do I change this template to only target */products* and not *products/page-name-here*. Would I just have to change the template name to something more specific?
2. Inside of this template, can I do an if statement something like the code below that will only target that */product* page? Let's say I end up keeping the template on all the pages, but I want to add code that only shows up if it's on */products* and not *products/page-name-here*. Maybe I could target it by its unique ID. How can I achieve this?

```
{% if page = 'page-name' %}
  // This will only show on /products.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is the "page-name-here" equivalent to the displays in the View you've shown us a screenshot of, or are they arbitrary names of products?

Comment: @beltouche correct the "page-name-here" is equivalent to the displays for example product/computers or /product/cell-phones

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display name as part of the template name to confer specificity to your Views templates, e.g., `[base template name]--[view machine name]--[view display id].html.twig`,

In your case, you could have names like `views-list--products_section--product_shop.html.twig`, `views-list--products_section--computers.html.twig`, `views-list--products_section--cell_phones.html.twig`, etc.

There's lot's of documentation out there, including [Create a template for a specific view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188529/create-a-template-for-a-specific-view), which may serve as a good jumping off point.